# getSerialVersionUID returns different values in Release than in Debug

Tags: java, android, serialization

I come across a very weird problem when working with serialVersionUID in a Serializable class.
When I run in Debug mode, code below returns the value -3853729081041647708 as set in the Session class:

```
public class Session implements Cloneable, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3853729081041647708L;
```

Code:

```
 ObjectStreamClass sess = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Session.class);
 long stu = sess.getSerialVersionUID();
```

But when I run in release mode however, it returns a totally unrelated value, namely -5810130834168560095

This leads to app not working correctly when installed by users. How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Proguard, it changes serialVersionUID to something else.
With

```
-keep public class com.xxx.Session
-keep public class * extends com.xxx.Session
-keepclassmembers class com.xxx.Session { *; }
```

everything works as expected